# MySQL Best Approach to get all days between two date values

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I need to find all dates that are within two dates. This would normally be done with

> BETWEEN

, but I have a StartDate and en EndDate column. This means that the date actually stretches over some days.

So a record could have values like this:

id, status, **startDate**, **endDate**

How can I find all rows, that are within those dates, provided I give the query a two dates.

Comment: Do you want to return records whose date range is entirely within the supplied dates, records whose date range entirely encompasses the supplied dates, or records whose date range has any overlap with the supplied dates?

Comment: I want all dates within and on two supplied dates.

Comment: I want those that encompasses...

Comment: Are there time components to your dates?

Comment: There isn't ^^ I was thinking of doing it through php after searching for the startdate.

Answer (score 2):

To get records where the complete record period lies in the requested period:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE startDate >= smallestDate AND 
      endDate <= largestDate;
```

To get records where the record period intersects the requested period:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE startDate <= largestDate AND 
      endDate >= smallestDate;
```

And, for completeness, to get the records where the start of the records period lies in the requested period, but you don't care about the end of the record period:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE startDate BETWEEN smallestDate AND largestDate
```

And, vice versa, for the end date of the record period:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE endDate BETWEEN smallestDate AND largestDate
```

(All examples assume `startDate` is always smaller than the `endDate`, of course.)